# printing sub array of array

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

The code below works correctly for a very specific case as I describe below.  I want to generalize it.  I am trying to print out sub arrays of arrays.

```
import numpy as np

alpha = input("input this number... ")
X = np.arange(alpha**2).reshape(alpha,alpha) #square matrix

beta  = input("a number in the matrix X")

if(beta > alpha**2): 
    print("must pick number inside array"), exit() 

print(X) #correct square matrix

00 01 02 03 04
05 06 07 08 09
10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24
```

I want to print a 3x3 sub array of this matrix X, independent of what  I choose alpha to be (independent of a 3x3 square or 5x5 square matrix,etc). As shown below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all values in the array are unique (as they are in both examples in your question):

```
[[i,j]] = numpy.argwhere(X==beta)
print(X[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2])
```

This code finds `(i, j)` indices in the 2D array such that `X[i,j]` is equal to `beta` value. And therefore `X[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2]` is 3x3 array with `beta` value in the center unless `beta` is on the edges of the matrix.

To get all available values even on the edges:

```
print(X[max(i-1,0):i+2,max(j-1,0):j+2])
```

Comment: @Integrals what is edge? It is `i == 0 or j == 0 or i == (alpha - 1) or j == (alpha - 1)`.

Comment: @Integrals  It is very basic. The code in the answer shows how to get (i,j) indices. The explicit conditions in my previous comment show how to find out whether `beta` is on the edge (by checking its indices: i,j). If you don't understand my comment; ask a separate question about how to detect that the input value `beta` is on the edge of the square numpy array.

Comment: @Integrals my comment uses `or` between conditions that works as is: you should not have replaced it with  commas. You should read a book (any book) on Python. It will save you time to avoid being stuck on trivial issues. There is a [list of free books in the Python tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
import numpy as np

alpha = input("input this number... ")
X = np.arange(alpha**2).reshape(alpha,alpha) #square matrix

beta  = input("a number in the matrix X")
if(beta > alpha**2): 
    print("must pick number inside array"), exit() 
row, col = beta // alpha, beta % alpha # This will give you the idxs of beta number in array
subsize = input("a size of submatrix you want to get")
border = (subsize - 1) // 2

subrand = np.array(X)[row - border: row + border + 1, col - border: col + border + 1]
print(subrand)
```